# Initial value in dart class

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I want to implement a points method, when user press on a button he earn some points.
my class look like this:

```
class User {
  String userEmail;
  String id;
  String token;
  String access;
  int points;

    User({
      @required this.userEmail,
      @required this.id,
      @required this.token,
      @required this.access,
      this.points = 0,
    });

  void raisePoints() {
    points = points + 2;
  }
}
```

This is how i initlaize the user when he sign in:

_

```
authUser = User(
        id: fireUser.uid,
        userEmail: fireUser.email,
        token: token,
        access: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken)
```

How do i set the value of points to zero at the first time he signed in, and how I set the amount of the points when the user sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the initial value, you can use

```
User({
  @required this.userEmail,
  @required this.id,
  @required this.token,
  @required this.access,
  this.points = 0, // <-- set to 0
});
```

And once you have created the user, you can increment/decrement points like:

```
User user = User(userEmail: "hi@gmail.com", id: "1", access: "true", token: "123");
user.points = 10;
```

or you can use

```
user.raisePoints();
```